# How to calculate margin/padding for different screen size after getting a ui design for a specified screen size

Tags: html, css, user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience

I got a design specification from a UI designer for a web app, he gave a design for 1440 x 1024 view and I am designing on a workstation with a view 1280 x 800 which brings about a conflict in margin, padding, and width specification.

How do calculate to suit the margin for my screen size and other screen sizes that is not 1440 x 1024?

Comment: you could use mediaqueries and define relative widths

Comment: Please review responsive design demos on w3school 'CSS Responsive
'. The link is: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Comment: Your question is too broad, sorry. There are simply too many possibilities. Widths in `vw`, heights in `vh`. Zoom out your browser to that it thinks your screen is 1440x1024. Make your design responsive so that it looks good everywhere and just happens to match your designer's design at 1440x1024. Etc.

Comment: Does that mean I should take note of the difference in pixels and subtract from smaller screen size??